# How to filter a dynamic datatable in primefaces? It is not working

Tags: primefaces

I have created a dynamic datatable in primefaces and tried to filter the columns but the filter is not working, help me please.

I have created a table where columns headers and values that is properties are rendered dynamically and iterated by the var of a datatable.

primefaces code below

```
<p:dataTable var="sales" value="#{customermisreportbean.custList}"
                            paginator="#{customermisreportbean.pagenatorActive}" rows="#{customermisreportbean.pagenatorActive?10:0}"
                            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" id="misreport" lazy="true"
                            filteredValue="#{customermisreportbean.filterval}" widgetVar="mistable">
                            <p:columns value="#{customermisreportbean.reportcolumns}"
                                var="column" filterBy="#{sales[column.property]}" columnIndexVar="colindex" headerText="#{column.header}">

                                <h:outputText value="#{sales[column.property]}"
                                    styleClass="#{column.align}" />
                            </p:columns>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

Below is the bean class

```
 public class columns implements Serializable{
        private String header="";
        private String property="";
        private String align="";



        public columns(String header, String property,String align) {

            this.header = header;
            this.property = property;
            this.align=align;
        }
        public String getHeader() {
            return header;
        }
        public void setHeader(String header) {
            this.header = header;
        }
        public String getProperty() {
            return property;
        }
        public void setProperty(String property) {
            this.property = property;
        }
        public String getAlign() {
            return align;
        }
        public void setAlign(String align) {
            this.align = align;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What is your PF version?

Comment: Primefaces version is 7.0